# Radio button array and JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, variables, radio-button, html

Making a JavaScript game for a school assignment and I'm in need of some help.

I've got a 5x5 grid of radio buttons, a start button and a table with a span inside to display points. Upon clicking the start button, the variable 'playing' becomes `true` and a random radio is selected. if a player clicks the selected radio, the points variable is `+1` and another random radio is selected.

So far I've managed to get the random radio select functions to work however I'm not really sure how to go about the rest. Not too sure how to check if a player clicks on the right radio button.

```
function SelectRadio(){
    var array = document.getElementsByName('radio'); //Selects all the radio buttons.
    var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*25)+1; // Selects a random number.
    array[randomNumber-1].checked = true; //Selects a random from the array.
}
```

Comment: I agree with @Frits, I just noticed it's a homework and added the Homework tag, I will keep my answer but I strongly recommend you understand the idea and not just copy paste.

Comment: Im changing it as needed, and not asking about everything, just that which I cant actually figure out alone... The other 300 lines of php and html was the easy bit xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made this jsFiddle, check it out and tell if you want other stuff.

[Checkboxes Game - JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/medopal/MDBU6/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/xBbXp/

```
var array = document.getElementsByName('radio');
var currentlyCheckedRadio;
var points = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i].onclick = function() {
        if(this == currentlyCheckedRadio) { // if clicked right one, increment points
            points = points + 1;
            alert('Yay, points: ' + points);
            SelectRadio(); // check another random
        } else {
            return false; // otherwise do nothing
        }
    };
}

function SelectRadio() {
    // Selects a random number.
    var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*25);

    currentlyCheckedRadio = array[randomNumber];

    //Selects a random from the array.
    currentlyCheckedRadio.checked = true;
}

SelectRadio();
```